# 404 Error in Codeigniter using virtual hosts, can't open a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, virtualhost, codeigniter-routing

I'm trying to get a local testing environment on my pc using

- codeigniter and
- virtual hosts.

I am debugging with xDebug installing in Netbeans. However...

I am able to open the very first page - the homepage. So "test.mydomain.local" opens without a problem.

But when I want to open the next page, like "test.mydomain.local/mycontroller" I get an 404 Error and I really don't know why... :(

I am a newbie in codeigniter and virtual hosts but I have some experience (about 3 years) in PHP, HTML, CSS.

Please help me! It's just about creating a testing environment - can't be so diffucult! :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: suggest providing some configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Try to select different values for $config['uri_protocol'] (./application/config/config.php):

- 'PATH_INFO'
- 'REQUEST_URI'
- 'QUERY_STRING'

And if it doesn't help you should check URL  "test.mydomain.local/index.php/mycontroller"

If both of the variants don't work you will check your .htaccess

Comment: Thanks for your answer! test.mydomain.local/index.php/mycontroller works! Not I just need to know how I can change this behaviour that there need to be "index.php" in the url. But I think I have already read about it in the codeigniter user guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your routing configuration located on `config/routes.php`